# Can bigtable instance only stores 1 week historical data?

Tags: bigtable

as mentioned on topic. I am trying to build a warehouse that only serves 1 week to 1 month data instead of all from genesis to reduce the cost. But the script provided from [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-bigtable/blob/master/warehouse-basic.sh) only supports upload service, which will stores all the historical data from start without pruning. Is there any mechanism to prune the historical data from bigtable?